# How accurate (or frequent) can scheduleTimer fire in Swift 4

Tags: swift4

this is my first question here. I am trying to learn Swift 4. I found some Stopwatch tutorials and examples, and have built my own version.

What is the accuracy/frequency of a scheduledTimer event? The example I found has code like this:

`timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

The UpdateTimer function simply added .1 to a counter and placed that value in a text property of a label.

I noticed that if I decreased the interval below .1, the 'time' displayed was not accurate. It appears to me that the scheduledTimer can't fire with accuracy faster than .1 seconds. To verify, I implemented a couple of date variables for Start/End times, and computed the difference. If I change the frequency of the scheduled timer to .001, there is a huge difference between the 'count' value updated in UpdateTimer versus the delta of my Start/End time.

My general assumption is that the tutorial is not a good example for a precise stopwatch, but I was trying to figure out how often the scheduledTimer could fire as I thought the Apple documentation indicated it could/would fire at .1 milliseconds: "The number of seconds between firings of the timer. If ti is less than or equal to 0.0, this method chooses the nonnegative value of 0.1 milliseconds instead."

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after searching more here, I finally found a few threads where people stated that timers were not reliable enough for a function like a stopwatch.

Comment: That is true that you shouldn't use a timer to count up the time.  But, you *can* use a timer to update the display of a running stopwatch, but the actual timing should be by computing the difference of a stored start time and the current time when the timer function runs.